# Merging micro batches in Spark Streaming

Tags: hdfs, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

(I have little knowledge about batch spark, but none on spark streaming)

#### Problem

I have a kafka topics `Kafka[(A,B)->X]` where `(A,B)` is the key (A and B are simple numeric types) and X is the message type, relatively big (couple of Mb). Putting aside the problem of failure in input, the data is a grid: for each `a` in `A`, there will be messages `(a,b)` for all `b` in `B`. Moreover, the b's are ordered and I think that we can assume that all messages for one `a` will arrive following the b's order  (what I know is that the topic is filled in this order).

Then I need to process the messages as follow:

1. a (couple of) function is applied on each message `(a,b)->x`, outputting `(a,b)->y`
2. a function should be applied on the messages `aB->Seq[y]` where `aB = {(a,b) for all b in B}`

(and later there is a pass where messages need to be "transposed" to be processed across all a's, but that's not the question here)

#### Question

How can I achieved such a merge of messages, from step 1 to step 2?

It looks like a groupby over the sub-key `a`, but to my understanding the method groupby would be applied per micro-batch. What I need is, for each `a`, to wait that all `b`'s are received (assume a simple counting system would work). Once again putting aside missing b and error in input data.

#### Some idea

Without knowledge, I would try to see if such merging could be achieved by appending to a hdfs file, one for each a. And try to trigger a second stream process on those files once full. I.e. when it contains all b, move the file to an input directory for step 2. But:

1. I don't know if such appending can be implemented on hdfs
2. Two sparkStreamingContext would need to run in parallel, one for each step. And that looks to be a problem (?).
3. I understood that passing by hdfs would break the "exactly once" property of spark (streaming)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a master RDD, and merge the micro RDDs generated by the stream to the master with `RDD.union`. Something like:

```
var masterRDD: RDD[(Long,Long), String] = sc.emptyRDD  // guessing on RDD type

myStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  if (! rdd.isEmpty) {
    masterRDD.union(rdd)

    masterRDD.groupBy(...).....
  }
})
```

You should take some time and **[read up](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing)** on checkpointing as well, specifically:

> **Data checkpointing** - Saving of the generated RDDs to reliable storage.
>   This is necessary in some stateful transformations that combine data
>   across multiple batches. In such transformations, the generated RDDs
>   depend on RDDs of previous batches, which causes the length of the
>   dependency chain to keep increasing with time. To avoid such unbounded
>   increases in recovery time (proportional to dependency chain),
>   intermediate RDDs of stateful transformations are periodically
>   checkpointed to reliable storage (e.g. HDFS) to cut off the dependency
>   chains.

Comment: That is a good start, and checkpointing looks to be a feature to look into, but it doesn't answer my problem :-\ There are two issues left: first,  I'd need masterRDD to be `RDD[Long, Seq[(Long,String)]]` and split micro `rdd` in it, and second I'd need a way to trigger step 2 only when the masterRDD values (i.e. the seq) has a suitable size.